# Find string in stripped binary file use gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

Does this debugger support this feature? Through `find` it is impossible, as the file `stripped`.

Answer (score 2):

You can install PEDA extension

```
$ git clone https://github.com/longld/peda.git ~/peda
$ echo "source ~/peda/peda.py" >> ~/.gdbinit
```

and use searchmem command

```
gdb-peda$ searchmem "text you are looking for"
```

it works the same for stripped binaries.